# A problem with beamer, tikz and fonts

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, fonts, incompatibility

I am having a weird problem with `beamer` and `tikz`. The following MWE doesn't compile. Removing the `\alert` from the author line, or the `\usepackage{tikz}` or the math content in the frame is enough to fix the problem. And on top of that, some of the errors in the log file are related to fonts, and the compiling process seems to involve many `mktextfm` processes.

This question may be too localized and the lack of relevant results in google pushes me to that conclusion. However, I believe I'm not the first one to compine these packages, my distribution is up-to-date, (as far as I can see) I'm not forgetting a brace or a backslash. What am I missing? Is there a simple cause lying below all these packages and explaining this issue?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\author{\alert{Foo Bar}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  $2+2=3$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### File list

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2013/01/04 3.26 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision e81e0c94bcc6)
beamerbasercs.sty    2013/01/04 (rcs-revision 9a97a4eee358)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2012/04/15 (rcs-revision cc6557182d97)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2010/04/27 (rcs-revision 982469101dd6)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbasefont.sty    2012/09/19  (rcs-revision 733629cd0c6c)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2012/02/24  (rcs-revision 2ff5461be705)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2012/11/11  (rcs-revision 6afbc49b1109)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2013/01/04  (rcs-revision 54309ceef997)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2012/12/26  (rcs-revision 1443917db2cf)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2012/08/30  (rcs-revision dfdb135076b3)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2012/09/13  (rcs-revision dcd846607320)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision d1a9b48be06d)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2012/10/02  (rcs-revision 5ed0f4010e8a)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2012/05/13  (rcs-revision 56972908a390)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2012/11/13  (rcs-revision ddfba79dac19)
enumerate.sty    1999/03/05 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2012/04/03  (rcs-revision 42a0f21a412d)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
 amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2004/08/06 v2.20
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
beamer_font.out
beamer_font.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
beamer_font.vrb
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
```

### Log file

```
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input at6

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: at6.log: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input at6' failed to make at6.tfm.
! Font U/msb/m/n/6=at6 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.10   $2
         +2=3$
! Missing endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                endgroup 
l.10   $2+2=3$

! Missing endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                endgroup 
l.10   $2+2=3$

! Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts.
<recently read> $

l.10   $2+2=3$

! Use of \end doesn't match its definition.
l.11 \end{
          frame}
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.11 \end{frame}

! Use of \end doesn't match its definition.
l.13 \end{
          document}

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 \end{d
           ocument}
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.13 \end{document}

)
! Emergency stop.
<*> \input beamer_font.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on beamer_font.log.

LaTeX exited abnormally with code 1 at Thu Feb 28 10:54:49
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your log file shows problems with fonts, which seem unrelated. If I process your MWE I get

```
! Argument of \next has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 \author{\alert{Foo Bar}}
```

and indeed tikz appears to leave the scratch macro `\next` with a slightly dangerous definition and beamer apparently uses it without checking if it's completely safe. making it safe lets the example run without error

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\let\next\relax
\author{\alert{Foo Bar}}
```

Comment: Thanks! It indeed works, I just have one doubt left: may this fix interfere with `tikz` features?

Comment: @T.Verron unlikely to have any bad effect: `\next` is used in Knuth's example macros in plain tex and the TeXBook just as a general scratch macro for local use, it just has some essentially random definition at the end of loading the package.